# Increasing speed using while loops: finding MULTIPLE chains of infection in R

Tags: r, performance, while-loop, tree

I recently asked a question about improving performance in my code ([Faster method than "while" loop to find chain of infection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865242/faster-method-than-while-loop-to-find-chain-of-infection-in-r)).

**Background:** 
I'm analyzing large tables (300 000 - 500 000 rows) that store data output by a disease simulation model. In the model, animals on a landscape infect other animals. For example, in the example pictured below, animal `a1` infects every animal on the landscape, and the infection moves from animal to animal, branching off into "chains" of infection.

In my original question, I asked how I could output a data.frame corresponding to animal "`d2`"s "chain of infection (see below, outlined in green, for illustration of one "chain"). The suggested solution worked well for one animal.

In reality, I will need to calculate chains for about 400 animals, corresponding to a subset of all animals (`allanimals` table).

[image]

I've included a link to an [example dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o6w29lz8yzryau/allanimals.csv?dl=0) that is large enough to play with.

Here is the code for one chain, starting with animal 5497370, and **note that I've slightly changed column names from my previous question, and updated the code!**

**The code:**

```
allanimals <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o6w29lz8yzryau/allanimals.csv?raw=1", 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Here's an example animal
ExampleAnimal <- 5497370


ptm <- proc.time()

allanimals_ID <- setdiff(unique(c(allanimals$ID, allanimals$InfectingAnimal_ID)), -1)

infected <- rep(NA_integer_, length(allanimals_ID))

infected[match(allanimals$ID, allanimals_ID)] <-
  match(allanimals$InfectingAnimal_ID, allanimals_ID)

path <- rep(NA_integer_, length(allanimals_ID))
curOne <- match(ExampleAnimal, allanimals_ID)
i <- 1
while (!is.na(nextOne <- infected[curOne])) {
  path[i] <- curOne
  i <- i + 1
  curOne <- nextOne
}

chain <- allanimals[path[seq_len(i - 1)], ]
chain

proc.time() - ptm

# check it out
chain
```

I'd like to output chains for each animal in "`sel.set`":

```
sel.set <- allanimals %>% 
  filter(HexRow < 4 & Year == 130) %>% 
  pull("ID")
```

If possible, **I'd like to store each "chain" data.frame as list with length = number of chains.**

Comment: It seems like this problem might be trivial to address in the data-generating step...

Comment: @Gregor Could you elaborate?

Comment: If it's possible to edit the code for the disease simulation model, it could include this information with the output.

Comment: It's really a graph theory problem, you might find an efficient way to do this in the `igraph` package.

Comment: @Gregor, that's the rub ;) I'm just one cog in this wheel - we can't change the output at this point.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you have a working method for finding the chain for one animal, and now you have a subset of animals that you want to find the chains for? Turn the method into a function `get_chain` and then `chains = list(); for(ani in sel.set) {chains[[ani]] <- get_chain(ani)}`, or just `chains = lapply(sel.set, get_chain)`.

Comment: F. Privé, I think I mistakenly approved your edit. Those "-1" animals are not "NA"s, they're just special in a different way. I need them to show up in the final chain table. @Gregor, yes! That's what I would have done (well - eventually) but F. Privé hinted at a faster solution...

Comment: @Nova Sorry then, remove the `setdiff` then. My answer will be ready in 2 mins :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll return the indices to access the data frame rather than all data frame subsets. You'll just need to use `lapply(test, function(path) allanimals[path, ])` or with a more complicated function inside the `lapply` if you want to do other things on the data frame subsets.

One could think of just `lapply` on the solution for one animal:

```
get_path <- function(animal) {
  curOne <- match(animal, allanimals_ID)
  i <- 1
  while (!is.na(nextOne <- infected[curOne])) {
    path[i] <- curOne
    i <- i + 1
    curOne <- nextOne
  }

  path[seq_len(i - 1)]
}

sel.set <- allanimals %>% 
  filter(HexRow < 4 & Year == 130) %>% 
  pull("ID")

system.time(
  test <- lapply(sel.set, get_path)
) # 0.66 seconds
```

We could rewrite this function as a recursive function (this will introduce my third and last solution).

```
system.time(
  sel.set.match <- match(sel.set, allanimals_ID)
) # 0

get_path_rec <- function(animal.match) {
  `if`(is.na(nextOne <- infected[animal.match]), 
       NULL, 
       c(animal.match, get_path_rec(nextOne)))
}

system.time(
  test2 <- lapply(sel.set.match, get_path_rec)
) # 0.06
all.equal(test2, test) # TRUE
```

This solution is 10 times as fast. I don't understand why though.

Why I wanted to write a recursive function? I thought you might have a lot of cases where you want for example to get the path of animalX and animalY where animalY infected animalX. So when computing the path of animalX, you would recompute all path of animalY. 
So I wanted to use memoization to store already computed results and memoization works well with recursive functions. So my last solution:

```
get_path_rec_memo <- memoise::memoize(get_path_rec)
memoise::forget(get_path_rec_memo)

system.time(
  test3 <- lapply(sel.set.match, get_path_rec_memo)
) # 0.12
all.equal(test3, test) # TRUE
```

Unfortunately, this is slower than the second solution. Hope it will be useful for the whole dataset.

Comment: THANK YOU! A lot of this is new for me, so it may take some time to go through and understand, but this will reduce my post-processing from days to minutes. I'll spend more time getting my head around it tomorrow when I'm back in the office. Really amazing stuff!

Comment: If you have questions regarding my answers, use [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152784/discussion-between-nova-and-f-prive).